# PHP - Create Signature using Nonce & Timestamp (JS & Python equivalent provided)

Tags: javascript, python, php, api, encryption

I'm trying to connect to an API and they only provide guides for python & Javascript.
I'm trying to find the equivalent for php but coming up short.

For additional reference: https://docs.deribit.com/#authentication

I'm unable to get the proper signature in PHP.

Javascript:

```
var timestamp = Date.now();
var nonce = "abcd";
var data = "";
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(`${timestamp}\n${nonce}\n${data}`, accessSecret).toString();
```

Python:

```
timestamp = round(datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000)
nonce = "abcd"
data = ""
signature = hmac.new(
    bytes(clientSecret, "latin-1"),
    msg=bytes('{}\n{}\n{}'.format(timestamp, nonce, data), "latin-1"),
    digestmod=hashlib.sha256
).hexdigest().lower()
```

PHP:
(*I don't know how to create the nonce)

```
$timestamp = number_format(microtime(true) * 1000, 0, '.', '');
$nonce = number_format(microtime(true) * 1000, 0, '.', '');
$data = "";

$key = $timestamp.$nonce.$data;
$sign = hash_hmac('sha256',$key,$secret);
$sign = bin2hex($sign);
```

Comment: For PHP, `$nonce = "abcd";`

Comment: @KenLee - this is just an example nonce they provide.

Comment: @KenLee https://docs.deribit.com/#authentication

Comment: Sure, you need to change the `abcd` to what you want. (I will give you an example shortly)

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the random generation required 'a-z0-9', 8 characters
you may please use `chr` and `rand` to do the job.

Hence try the following

```
<?php
$x1=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x2=   chr(rand(0,9)+48) ;
$x3=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x4=   chr(rand(0,9)+48) ;
$x5=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x6=   chr(rand(0,9)+48) ;
$x7=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x8=   chr(rand(0,9)+48) ;

$nonce = $x1.$x2.$x3.$x4.$x5.$x6.$x7.$x8;

?>
```